# CoreData(swift) memory issue while inserting thousands of records

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-management

My application is in swift(latest version) language, And its has a bit complex database structure.
I'm dumping records while app launch first time as app must support offline information, My app can have millions of records.
Now Saving records in entities, which has the relationship with around 14-15 entity(one to one and one to many).
My Application through memory warning and gets terminated after around 1000 thousand records. I tried with profiling for leakages but that time app is working fine, however, it take a long time.

I have tried to create singleton class of context manager and also tried with creating local kind of variable while inserting a chunk of records.
For now, I'm fetching 50 records from web API and saving my context by updating my entities.

I have tried with autoreleasepool, but no success.

Please suggest me what should it do?

Thank you 
Ashwin

Comment: Take a look at "Reducing Memory Overhead" here. Maybe it can help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to watch this video. It is very inspiring and explains a lot of useful things about core data:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/211/

Are you using *fetchBatchSize* property?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506558-fetchbatchsize

Comment: Thank for links actually not getting what is the cause of the app termination. Its working fine in case of fewer data. Digging and hunting for the actual cause.

Comment: If you are getting memory warning the problem is in memory management for sure. Overtime you fetch from core data you create objects in memory. if you are fetching all at once a million objects you have all of them in memory. Now if you put them in a for loop and you duplicate them in order to insert these objects in DB (with relative sync logic, so check if the object is already there, update it or eventually insert it) of course causes the allocated memory to be doubled at least. the fetchBatchSize prop should help with that. If you share the sync code we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing large amounts of Core Data objects in a loop, then you need to periodically save the context so that core data can turn modified objects back into faults instead of keeping them in memory. How often you need to save and when depends on your application and the code you are using to process, which it would be helpful to see in your question. You'll need to experiment yourself to find a balance between speed and memory use.

Use the allocations instrument and you will see where your memory is going. You're not leaking memory, you're just using too much of it.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing same. Only 50/100 records at a time.

Comment: Please show your code in the question. It's very hard to help without that.

Answer (score -1):

Disable zombie object of your project. Below I have posted how to disable zombie object follow it via images.

For more details about zombie object  [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/EradicatingZombies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH82-SW1)

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]